# Play a Wistia video with a button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, video

The button of the Wistia video is not from the original embed code, since it has to be customized. What would the callback function look like? I can choose between API embded code and the iframe one below.I'd like to be able to "click" the iframe with jQuery when my custom button is hit.

Video embed code:

```
<iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/ff0oaf33o5?videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"
                scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen
                webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="1000" height="563"></iframe>
        <script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/iframe-api-v1.js"></script>
        <script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
        <script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a custom play button outside of the embedded Wistia video, you can trigger the play() method to start the video with a click() event.

```
$('#play-button').click(function()
{
    wistiaApi.play();
});
```

This will only play the video and will not pause it.
If the video is paused, you may click

```
#play-button
```

to resume the video.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please would you add some explanation to your code to explain what it does and how it solves the problem - this will help others in the future